# Does a Fey Beast Companion share your actions?

Tags: dnd-4e

Looking at [Fey Beast Tamer](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=915) in DDI, there are no indications about how it takes its turns, performs movements, or attacks.

Is there an online reference providing rules for how the creature takes actions somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Glossary of the Compendium has a listing for [Fey Beast companion Actions](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/mobile/display.aspx?page=Glossary&id=614):

It boils down the following:

- Standard - you have to take your standard to give it one
- Move - When you take a move action it can also take a move action, you can stay put, but it still consumes your move
- Minor - It consumes your minor action
- Free action - naturally it can always take free actions.
- Triggered actions - can only be done if you are allowed to make the same trigger (IE if you still have an immediate action left, if you are free to make opportunity attacks etc). (note it consumes your action of the action it takes, so if it takes an immediate, you are using your immediate to tell it to move, same with OA).
- Can act independently - if it is farther than 20 squares away from you or you are unconscious then it can still act, but only has a single action. It can still take opportunity and free actions, but cannot take immediate actions.

Comment: Unless I read it wrong, the Fey Beast can act on its own OA, only you offer your up for that turn. P106 : Triggered Actions: If one of your fey beast companion's triggered actions is triggered, the companion can take that action only if you takes the same kind of action to command it to do so. Example, if an enemy adjacent to your companion provokes an opportunity attack from it, you must take an opportunity action to command your companion to make the attack.

Comment: @ExoWaltz that's correct. I'll clarify here